# umount /mnt deleted home directory

Tags: wubi, home-directory, umount

I did something incredibly stupid: while tinkering with mount / umount trying to relocate some space, I did as I read on one website, and dit

```
sudo umount -f /mnt
```

(I don't remember whether I used -f or some other command to force it)

And when I did it, it suddenly crashed ubuntu. Then I couldn't access my profile (because of lack of home directory)
I tried this: [Deleted home directory. Please help](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92521/deleted-home-directory-please-help)

And it worked, but the problem is, that this new home folder doesn't have any of my old files.

**So the question is:
Is this unmounting reversible? Or were my files deleted?**

**To rephrase the question**: what could happen while unmounting /mnt ? What can I do to link my old home folder with new?

Typing

```
editor /etc/fstab
```

got

```
file system < mount point < type
proc /proc
/host/ubuntu/disks/root.disk /
/host/ubuntu/disks/swap.disk none
```

(sorry it took so long, I had problems accesing it)

**Another question:**
What is the difference with /etc/fstab data and the data which can be retrieved by df -h? I manipulated with filesystem using info from df -h and now the info from fstab confuses me

Comment: If this isn't a standard filesystem setup (if you've got /home from another partition for example), please edit your question to include the content of `/etc/fstab`

Comment: Please do what Oli asked above, we cannot guess. And if you want to rephrase your question (not advisable at the moment) then do it by **editing the question**, not in a comment.

Comment: What is this system? That fstab is most irregular.

Comment: You mean is this NTFS or something else? It's NTFS

Comment: I mean that most systems mount a device on / rather than another path (relative to /host/)... When you say this is NTFS, do you mean it's a Wubi install?

Comment: It is Wubi install.

Comment: In a Wubi install, it is possible that the force unmount corrupted the root.disk file itself - you may be able to recover it by booting into Windows and running chkdsk from there - see http://askubuntu.com/questions/228709/ubuntu-12-04-wubi-not-starting-root-disk-corrupted

Comment: @steeldriver I did chkdsk (strange, when I did it before, nothing happened). Now when I enter linux I get
    The disk contains an unclean file system (0,0)
    The file system wasn't safely closed on Windows. Fixing.

But it actually doesn't fix anything.

Answer (score 1):

Mounting and unmounting is a *runtime* thing. They don't write anything to disk - they just alter the in-kernel way the filesystem is mapped. Mouts are loaded from `/etc/fstab` so unless you've changed that, just restarting the computer would get things back in order. `sudo mount -a` might even work. It might not.

What would happen on a ***normal system*** if you forcefully unmounted /mnt is you would unmount the root filesystem (they would be the same device). The computer would grind to a halt near-instantaneously. On a normal computer, restarting would follow /etc/fstab and remount / (and everything in it, including /mnt) and put everything back in the right place.

In short: Reboot (or boot to a LiveCD for added safety) then see what the damage actually is.

Comment: "Mounting and unmounting is a runtime thing. They don't write anything to disk - they just alter the in-kernel way the filesystem is mapped. "
I'm clueless. I don't understand why it crashed ubuntu.
Tried restarting - didn't do any good.
I also tried "mount -a".

Would appreciate any help on what should I google (how to extract important information about fstab)

Comment: Also, what's happening with the files when one umounts /mnt? Is this actually deleted, or does it only change location on physical disk? How to comprehend answer to this question?

Comment: What do you mean restart didn't do any good? What are you left with?

Comment: ***Nothing*** happens to the files on disk when you unmount something. That's my point. They just become inaccessible through their old mountpoint until they're mounted again (which should be boot).

Comment: After creating home folder, as in provided link, I am able to access, but I don't see my old files. I'm also getting errors when I try to install something (as it needs access to nonaccessible files).

If nothing happens, then the problem is to access them again - but I don't know how to do it. Rebooting didn't help. When I first rebooted I couldn't even enter desktop, as there was something like 'couldn't access home directory', but using the link which I pasted helped.